# Is there any way to find out the number of active notifications from my Android App?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I am working towards managing the notifications that my app creates in the Android device. Is there any method that can provide me the **number of notifications** from my app that are **active** (i.e. still visible in the notification drawer) at any given time?

Comment: Via the various `PendingIntent` options, you can find out if the user gets rid of it, and you know when *you* get rid of it, so you should be able to keep track of this yourself.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`NotificationManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) for getting list of all the active notifications posted by your application using [`getActiveNotifications()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#getActiveNotifications())

As per the reference doc for `getActiveNotifications()`:

> Recover a list of active notifications: ones that have been posted by the calling app that have not yet been dismissed by the user or cancelled by the app.

Answer (score 1):

to expand on commonswares comment:

I see two approaches here:

1) manage this number via a count sharedpreferences or a database, etc. you will need to supply a deleteIntent which starts something to update this number when they dismiss the notification and a contentIntent for when they open the notification (this will also update your count).

2) read this number explicitly from a notification listener service.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html

#1 is much preferred because the user doesn't have to opt in to the behavior and asking for their full notification list is entirely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun getNotificationCount(): Int {
    return notificationManager.activeNotifications.size
}
```